# Sorting Dictionaries by Internal State of Value in Python

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7, dictionary

How can we sort a dictionary in python using the internal state of the value?

For example:

```
myDict = {'a': {'day': [0, 1, 2, 5], 'week': [4, 3, 1, 2, 3]},
          'b': {'day': [0, 6, 2, 5], 'week': [4, 3, 1, 2, 3]}}
```

I want to sort the dictionary keys by the second value of the day list for their corresponding value dictionaries.

Comment: Dictionaries can't be sorted, what was the output you had in mind?

Comment: ["a", "b"] as (1 < 6) or a tuple representing the same.

Comment: So you want just the keys in the sorted order?

Comment: Yes, but sorted based on a value in their day lists in their value objects.

Comment: Checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value, but its not clear how to sort based on a more complex value object (like a dict in this case). itemgetter does not work with str

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort that like this

```
print sorted(myDict, key=lambda v: myDict[v]['day'][1])
# ['a', 'b']
```

The `key` parameter accepts a function which will be used to determine the value to be used for the current item during the sorting.

As `sorted` iterates over the `myDict`, we get each and every key. So, for each key, we pick the second element in the `day` dictionary and use it as the value which represents the key during sorting.

What we have done is, when sorting function looks for a value of `a` we return `1` and when it looks for `b` we return `6`.

Comment: This is what I needed. The question marked as a duplicate does not address this specific case.